# Linear Algebra: Proving Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{P} = \begin{pmatrix}\boldsymbol{u} & \boldsymbol{v} & \boldsymbol{w}\end{pmatrix}$ be $3\times 3$ matrices where $\boldsymbol{u},$ $\boldsymbol{v}$ and $\boldsymbol{w}$ are columns of $\boldsymbol{P}$ such that
>   $$\boldsymbol{Au}=a\boldsymbol{u},\quad \boldsymbol{Av}=b\boldsymbol{v},\quad\text{and} \quad\boldsymbol{Aw}=c\boldsymbol{w}$$
>   for some real numbers $a,$ $b$ and $c.$
>
> Show that if $\boldsymbol{P}$ is invertible then
>   $\boldsymbol{A} = \boldsymbol{P}\begin{pmatrix}a & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & b & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & c\end{pmatrix}\boldsymbol{P}^{-1}.$

Can anyone help me with this problem? I am having a hard time understanding and interpreting this question as it's my first time learning about linear algebra. Thank you so much!

Comment: Where's the problem?

Comment: I think you forgot to type the question

Comment: Sorry! I've added the question now! thanks! :)

Comment: Basically, it means that $PA=(au,bv,cw)$

Comment: Ok, but how do i go about proving the statement?

Answer (score 4):

Let $D = \begin{pmatrix}a & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & b & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & c\end{pmatrix}$. The statement $A = PDP^{-1}$ is equivalent to the statement $AP = PD$.

We now show that these two matrices are equal, by showing that their columns are equal, i.e. that $APe_1 = PDe_1,~ APe_2 = PDe_2,~ APe_3 = PDe_3$, where $e_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, e_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, e_3 = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ are the standard unit vectors.

So let's check that:

$$APe_1 = Au = au = aPe_1 = Pae_1 = PDe_1,$$

$$APe_2 = Av = bv = bPe_2 = Pbe_2 = PDe_2,$$

$$APe_3 = Aw = cw = cPe_3 = Pce_3 = PDe_3.$$

We're done. Note that $AP = PD$ is also true if $P$ is not invertible, but in that case it doesn't make sense to write $A = PDP^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since it given that $A\mathbf{u}=a\mathbf{u}$, $A\mathbf{v}=b\mathbf{v}$ and $A\mathbf{w}=c\mathbf{w}$ for some $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$, we can infer that $a,b,c$  are eigen values and $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}$ are eigen vectors of the matrix $A$.

Now suppose that the given matrix $P$ is invertible. Since $P$ is invertible, the column vectors $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}$ are linearly independent, and thus $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}$ are linearly independent eigen vectors of the matrix $A$. Since $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}$ are linearly independent eigen vectors, the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable, and we can write

$A=P\Lambda P^{-1}$   where $\Lambda=\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 & 0\\ 0 & b & 0\\0 & 0 & c\end{bmatrix}$

QED